# Python BS4 print write error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ini

I am trying to write a code to grab some data from a website using Python3, as you can see from the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import sys
headers={}
headers['User-Agent']="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"
req=urllib.request.Request('http://www.cjcyw.com/a/chuanbodangan/2015/0930/47853.html',headers=headers)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
xml=BeautifulSoup(resp,'html.parser')
x=xml.findAll('dd')
for item in x:
    item=item.text.encode('utf-8')
    print(sys.stdout.buffer.write(item))
```

The result is like this:

[image: result1]

when i write this data into a txt file:

i use str to debug,the real problem is pop out:

[image: buggggggg]

Comment: in the 4.txt file show numbers but not the result i want.

Comment: Why are you using `sys.stdout.buffer.write`? Try `f.write(item)`.

Comment: And I don't think `.encode()` is needed here.

Comment: thx,but "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Tag",and if i use file.write(item.txt), "UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence"

Comment: First, I forgot about use `str()` function like `str(item)`. Then, the text's encoding is *GBK* ?

Comment: UTF-8 it seems the website used mixed encoding~str(item) can print part of the data with a UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\xa0' in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence"

Comment: Well, I understand now. Let me post an answer and explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.strings` here. [strings](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import sys
headers={}
headers['User-Agent']="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36"            req=urllib.request.Request('http://www.cjcyw.com/a/chuanbodangan/2015/0930/47853.html',headers=headers)
resp=urllib.request.urlopen(req)
xml=BeautifulSoup(resp,'html.parser')
x=xml.findAll('dd')

file = open("4.txt", 'a')
for item in x:
    s = ""
    for string in item.strings:
        s += string
    s += "\n"
    file.write(s)
file.close()
```

all code is pasted.

Comment: not work but thx,i think maybe run the code first ,and then maybe more helpful

Comment: I have already run the code. I will paste my whole code here. You can run it . and get the correct txt.

Answer (score 0):

First, as I said, Don't use `sys.stdout.buffer.write` here, just use `f.write(str(item))` instead.

Then, because Microsoft Windows Chinese version's default file encoding is **GBK**. And the text's encoding seems like **UTF-8**. So you need open the file in **UTF-8** encoding like this:

```
open('4.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8")
```

And try run your code.